# phpSPO and authentication

Tags: php, sharepoint

I need to access a file on SharePoint and I have installed phpSPO via Composer.

I use this code:

```
require_once('/vendor/autoload.php');

$username = 'myUsername';
$password = 'myPassword';
$fileUrl = "file-url";
$fileUrl = end(explode("https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com", $fileUrl));

use Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\Auth\AuthenticationContext;
use Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\ClientContext;
use Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\ListCreationInformation;
use Office365\PHP\Client\SharePoint\SPList;

$authCtx = new AuthenticationContext('https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com');
```

But I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\Auth\AuthenticationContext" not found ...

From composer.json:

```
{ 
    "require": { 
        "vgrem/php-spo": "^2.5" 
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Solution:

```
use Office365\Runtime\Auth\AuthenticationContext;
use Office365\SharePoint\ClientContext;
use Office365\SharePoint\ListCreationInformation;
use Office365\SharePoint\SPList;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed that class? [SPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) classes are in `vgrem/php-spo` package. Check for this package in composer.json to make sure that it is already there and run `composer update` to update them.

Comment: From composer.json. {
    "require": {
        "vgrem/php-spo": "^2.5"
    }
}